# Converting user custom date format string to nsdate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter

Suppose, an user has set a custom date format in the Languages and Region section of System Preferences. Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfFoT.jpg

I have this date in NSString representation (`eg - @"201603/11"`) and I'd like to convert it to my own date format i.e. "MM/dd/yyyy". I'm using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
formatter.dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MM/dd/yyyy"
                                                       options:0
                                                        locale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSDate *localDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"201603/11"];
```

But localDate always returns nil.

In short, my NSString representation is 201603/11 (format set by user), and I'd like to get this in NSDate representation.

Comment: your date formatter is wrong.  short style is to get the date in short as a string.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, yes the problem lies with my dateformatter. I have removed the dateStyle property, however still localDate returns nil. Any clue?

Comment: [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyydd/MM"];

Comment: "yyyydd/MM" is something user has set in the preferences (see screenshot in the question). I have a string representation of date in the format set by user. I want to convert to an NSDate representation in "MM/dd/yyyy".

Comment: It will give you a date, later you can convert it into your required format. First you need to set the formatter to match the format of the user set string.

Comment: @"yyyydd/MM" is an example though. User can set any format in the preferences (eg ddyyyy/MM, MM/yy), what should I be doing then? I can't hardcode the date format right?

Comment: 1. use `currentLocale` instead of `systemLocale`. 2. the format of the formatter is "yMM/dd/" instead of "yyyyMM/dd/".

Answer (score 0):

```
// User Date format
NSDateFormatter *userFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[userFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyyMM/dd"];

NSDate *localDate = [userFormatter dateFromString:@"201610/31"];

NSLog(@"%@",localDate); //You will get, Year: 2016, Month:10, Day: 31

// The date format you want
NSDateFormatter *myFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[myFormatter setDateFormat: @"MM/dd/yyyy"];

// Get date string from your local date object
NSString *myDateString = [myFormatter stringFromDate:localDate];
NSLog(@"%@",myDateString); //You will get a string, 10/31/2016
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But you're hard coding the date format in the second line. The user can set any date format in System Preferences in OS X. What then?